# Retrieve the self-generated _id value of the object after pushing it to a existing collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb document, let's say having the schema

```
class: String,
class_teacher: String,
students: [
    { 
       student: String,
       marks: number
    }
]
```

In the above example if I push a new student to the collection, it'll generate a `_id` for each student and I am doing it by using the update query for the entire document.

1. Is it the right way to do it?
2. If yes, how can I get the _id for each student as soon as I push the student object?
3. After some time, if I want to update the marks of a single student, what is the best way to do it??

Comment: It works best if you only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nice mode, I'll answer **all** of your "questions", here is some demonstration code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var classSchema = new Schema({
  class: String,
  teacher: String,
  students: [{ student: String, marks: Number }]
});

var Class = mongoose.model("Class", classSchema);

var myclass = new Class();

myclass.students.push(
  { student: "bill", marks: 10 },
  { student: "ted", marks: 5 }
);

console.log("Whole:\n %s\n",myclass);
console.log("Last added _id: %s\n",myclass.students.slice(-1)[0]._id);

myclass.save(function(err,myclass) {
  if (err) throw err;

  Class.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "students.student": "ted" },
    { "$set": { "students.$.marks": 7 } },
    function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log(doc);
    }
  );

});
```

So overall:

1. Sure not a problem, even though you might find defining your schema for "Student" separately to be a bit more maintainable in the long run:

   ```
   var studenSchema = new Schema({
       student: String,
       marks: Number
   });

   var classSchema = new Schema({
       class: String,
       teacher: String,
       students: [studentSchema]
   });
   ```
2. Well the last added element in the array when you modify this way can just be pulled off with `.slice()`, then you can get the last `_id` value.

   ```
   console.log("Last added _id: %s\n",myclass.students.slice(-1)[0]._id);
   ```
3. Updating marks can be best done with `.findOneAndUpdate()` or a similar operation. Here you query to match the document and array element and update the correct one with use of the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator:

   ```
   Class.findOneAndUpdate(
     { "students.student": "ted" },
     { "$set": { "students.$.marks": 7 } },
     function(err,doc) {
       if (err) throw err;

       console.log(doc);
     }
   );
   ```

This also returns the document that is modified so you can see the changes. For "bulk" operations you would use the `.update()` method along with the "multi" option.

You can also "add" new students to the array using the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator, and just as before the document is returned with the method shown, so you could also apply getting the new `_id` value that way:

```
  Class.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "students.student": "ted" },
    { "$push": { "students": { "student": "sally", "marks": 4 }} },
    function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log("Whole:\n %s", doc);
      console.log("Last added _id: %s\n",doc.students.slice(-1)[0]._id);
    }
  );
```

And that produces results like this:

```
Whole:
{ _id: 53bc9844c1cbd4d24eac8db6,
  __v: 0,
  students:
   [ { student: 'bill', marks: 10, _id: 53bc9844c1cbd4d24eac8db7 },
     { student: 'ted', marks: 7, _id: 53bc9844c1cbd4d24eac8db8 },
     { student: 'sally', marks: 4, _id: 53bca6c346d93b32624e5af4 } ] }

Last added id: 53bca6c346d93b32624e5af4
```

If you need other schema validation features or other hooks on field values then you will need to individually `.find()` documents, modify in code and then `.save()`. But these are the alternate approaches, which usually create less "wire traffic" than dealing with whole documents.

Comment: +1 for the efforts, I am learning(actually enjoying) mongoose from your answers :)

Comment: Thank you.. It is really detailed and well informative.